# fullVisitorId giving error name for sessions report

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a simple query that shows # of sessions by day, by source and medium, however I keep getting an error: Unrecognized name: fullVisitorId at [2:1]

Here's my code:

```
SELECT traffic_source.source AS source, traffic_source.medium AS medium, event_date,
fullVisitorId,
  SUM(totals.visits) as visits,
  SUM(totals.pageviews) as pageviews,
COUNT(*) AS sessions
FROM `nth-glider-369017.analytics_316822874.events_*`
GROUP BY traffic_source.source, traffic_source.medium, event_date
```

Should I change it from fullVisitorID to something else?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the table name you are using the GA4 export to BigQuery but trying to execute queries that were written for the Universal Analytics (GA3) export.

The schema is different and the new export replaced fullVisitorId and clientId with the user_pseudo_id

A couple of resources for the new export that will provide you with queries for the new export:

- https://adswerve.com/blog/ga4-bigquery-guide-users-and-sessions-part-one/
- https://developers.google.com/analytics/bigquery/basic-queries
- https://developers.google.com/analytics/blog/2022/hll